# I'm trying to build a proof in Coq that two different permutation definitions are equivalent, but the non-inductive side is not working

Tags: logic, permutation, coq, proof, induction

The two definitions are these:

```
Inductive perm : list nat -> list nat -> Prop :=

| perm_eq: forall l1, perm l1 l1

| perm_swap: forall x y l1, perm (x :: y :: l1) (y :: x :: l1)

| perm_hd: forall x l1 l2, perm l1 l2 -> perm (x :: l1) (x :: l2)

| perm_trans: forall l1 l2 l3, perm l1 l2 -> perm l2 l3 -> perm l1 l3.
```

```
Fixpoint num_oc (x: nat) (l: list nat): nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => 0 
  | h::tl => 
    if (x =? h) then S (num_oc x tl) else num_oc x tl
  end.

Definition equiv l l' := forall n:nat, num_oc n l = num_oc n l'.
```

The theorem that I'm trying to prove is this:

```
Theorem perm_equiv: forall l l', equiv l l' <-> perm l l'.
```

The `perm -> equiv` direction is ready, but the `equiv -> perm` direction isn't working. I tried this strategy:

```
- intro H. unfold equiv in H.
    generalize dependent l'.
    induction l.
    + intros l' H. admit.
    + intros l' H. simpl in H.

      generalize dependent l'.

      intro l'. induction l'.

      * intro H. specialize (H a).

        rewrite <- beq_nat_refl in H.

        simpl in H. Search False.

        inversion H.

        destruct (a =? a0) eqn:Ha.

        ** simpl in H. inversion H.

        ** apply False_ind.

           apply beq_nat_false in Ha.

           apply Ha. reflexivity. 

      * destruct (x =? a). *).
```

I'm out of ideas for the first branch, so it's admitted for now, but the second one is crashing at the destruct tactic. How do I proceed with this proof?

Comment: Can you please add the definition of `num_oc`?

Comment: Fixpoint num_oc (x: nat) (l: list nat): nat :=
  match l with
  | nil => 0
  | h::tl => if (x =? h) then S (num_oc x tl) else num_oc x tl
end.

Answer (score 4):

You should attempt to write a proof on paper before attempting to encode it in Coq. Here is a possible strategy.

### Nil case

When `l = []`, you know that every number in `l'` occurs zero times because of `H`. It should be possible to prove an auxiliary lemma that implies that `l' = []` in this case. You can conclude with `perm_eq`.

### Cons case

Suppose that `l = x :: xs`. Let `n = num_oc x xs`. We know that `num_oc x l' = S n` by `H`. You should be able to prove a lemma saying that `l'` is of the form `ys1 ++ x :: ys2` where `num_oc x ys1 = 0`. This would allow you to show that `equiv xs (ys1 ++ ys2)`. By the induction hypothesis, you find that `perm xs (ys1 ++ ys2)`. Hence, by `perm_hd`, `perm (x :: xs) (x :: ys1 ++ ys2)`.

You should be able to prove that `perm` is a transitive relation and that `perm (x :: ys1 ++ ys2) (ys1 ++ x :: ys2)` holds. Combined with the last assertion, this will yield `perm l l'`.

---

The main takeaway in this case is that attempting to write every proof with single, direct induction is only going to work for the simplest results. You should start thinking about how to break down your results into simpler intermediate lemmas that you can combine to prove your final result.

Comment: Thank you Arthur, can you help me with some other issue on this same code?
Coq shows an error on the following lemma :

Lemma equiv_to_perm: forall l l', equiv l l' -> perm l l'.
Proof.
 
  induction l.
  - intros.
    apply equiv_nil in H. 
    rewrite H. apply perm_eq.
       
  - unfold equiv in *. intros. simpl in H. 
    generalize dependent l'. intro l'.
    induction l'.

    -- intro H. specialize (H a).
       rewrite <- beq_nat_refl in H.
       simpl in H. inversion H.
       
    -- apply perm_app_cons.
 
Qed.

Saying that it can't unify 'nat' with hypothesis

Comment: This is the environment: 

In environment

a : nat

l : list nat

IHl : forall l' : list nat, (forall n : nat, num_oc n l = num_oc n l') -> perm l l'

a0 : nat

l' : list nat

IHl' : (forall n : nat, (if n =? a then S (num_oc n l) else num_oc n l) = num_oc n l') -> 
perm (a :: l) l'

Unable to unify "nat" with "forall n : nat, (if n =? a then S (num_oc n l) else num_oc n l) 
= num_oc n (a0 :: l')".

Comment: And this is the definition of that applied lemma:

Lemma perm_app_cons: forall l1 l2 a, perm (a :: l1 ++ l2) (l1 ++ a :: l2).

Proof.

  induction l1.

  - intros l2 a.

    simpl.

    apply perm_eq.

  - intros l2 a2. (* porque o coq usa o 'a' como o numero natural?*)

    simpl.

    apply perm_trans with (a :: a2 :: l1 ++ l2).

    + apply perm_swap.

    + apply perm_hd.

      apply IHl1.

Qed.

Any advice on how to solve this error? Thank you for your time

Comment: Hi @Andrey, could you please add the code as an edit to your original post? You can use the formatting syntax to display it in monospace font: https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help.